# Import Large Dataset consisting 50,000 Rows from another Google Sheet using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need help in script tweaking. I am trying to import a large data from another google sheet which consist of 25 columns and approximately 50,000 rows. Previously, I have tried ImportRange function and ImportLargeData script but maybe because of large data those doesn't work anymore.

Previously, I have used following script and it was working fine:

```
function importLargeData() {
  // Replace these with the actual values
  const sourceSheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ZNBKBNFCBCAISDYAJTIJYLSUO/edit";
  const sourceRange = "INDEX!A1:Y50000";
  const destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INDEX_COPIED");

  // Get the data from the source sheet
  const values = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourceSheetUrl).getRange(sourceRange).getValues();

  // Process the data if needed (optional)

  // Write the data to the destination sheet
  destinationSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

After execution of the script only 800 rows were imported before showing the time out error:

Execution log:

```
1:48:15 PM Notice Execution started
1:54:15 PM Error  Exceeded maximum execution time
```

Though this script is not working on my new file, the same script is working fine in another Google Sheet. After that, I have tried another script but it did not either:

```
/* Global configuration */
const CONFIG = {
  URL: {
    /* Enter the source sheet url between '' */
    SOUCE_SHEET_URL: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ZNBKBNFCBCAISDYAJTIJYLSUO/edit',
  },
  SHEET_TO_COPY: {
    /* Enter the source sheet name between '' */
    SHEET_NAME: 'INDEX',
  },
  SPREADSHEET: {
    ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
  },
  TOAST: {
    T1: 'Sheet found, deleting the current version.',
    T2: 'Sheet not found, copying the new sheet.',
    T3: 'Sheet copied successfully.',
    T4: 'Enter the correct url and sheet name.',
  }
};

const importSheet = () => {
  try {
    const sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(CONFIG.URL.SOUCE_SHEET_URL).getSheetByName(CONFIG.SHEET_TO_COPY.SHEET_NAME);
    /* Before copying the sheet, delete the exiting copy (if any) */
    const existingSheet = CONFIG.SPREADSHEET.ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET.getSheetByName(CONFIG.SHEET_TO_COPY.SHEET_NAME);
    if (existingSheet) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(CONFIG.TOAST.T1, 'Status', 3);
      Utilities.sleep(2000);
      CONFIG.SPREADSHEET.ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET.deleteSheet(existingSheet);
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(CONFIG.TOAST.T2, 'Status', 3);
      Utilities.sleep(2000);
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    const destinationSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(CONFIG.SPREADSHEET.ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET);
    destinationSheet.setName(CONFIG.SHEET_TO_COPY.SHEET_NAME);
    CONFIG.SPREADSHEET.ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET.setActiveSheet(destinationSheet);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(CONFIG.TOAST.T3, 'Success', 3);
  }
  catch (err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(CONFIG.TOAST.T4, 'Failed', 3);
  }
};
```

Execution log:

```
1:58:38 PM Notice Execution started
2:04:38 PM Error  Exceeded maximum execution time
```

The dataset "Index" is a dynamic table and the number of rows could increase in future. Is there any way around to import the large data?

NB: I am new in script writing and do not know much about it.

Comment: From `consist of 25 columns and approximately 50,000 rows`, it seems that the values of 1,250,000 cells are required to be copied. So, how about using Sheets API instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp)? [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your current issue. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Tanaike, though my sheet is a simple various product movement analysis with dates/references, I don't know much to try out the API/Script on my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to copy values from one sheet to another using  sheets api:

```
function myfunk40() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let [hs, ...vs] = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(), `${sh.getName()}!${"A1:B"}`).values;
  let orow = osh.getLastRow();
  if (!orow) {
    vs.unshift(hs);
    let a1 = osh.getRange(1, 1).getA1Notation();
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: vs }, ss.getId(), `${osh.getName()}!${a1}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" })
  } else {
    let a1 = osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).getA1Notation();
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: vs }, ss.getId(), `${osh.getName()}!${a1}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" })
  }
}
```